# Checkbox Rendering Parameter is taking value from standard values if not checked

Tags: rendering-parameters

`Using Sitecore 10.1`

I have a rendering parameter with two fields - `Checkbox` (*Show Icon*) & a `Single-Line textbox` (*Css Class*).
The standard values for this rendering parameter template are set to checked & empty respectively.

When reading these values for a page rendering, if I uncheck *Show Icon*, the value is still "1".
But, if I uncheck *Show Icon* and add some value to *Css Class*, then value of checkbox is null (as expected).

Why is this behavior. Is the rendering parameter for checkbox reading from std. value if unchecked. If I uncheck the checkbox in the std. value, it is working as expected.

Could this be a bug in Sitecore?

**Action method:**

```
Mymodel model = new Mymodel(Sitecore.Context.Item)
                {
                    ShowIcon = Utility.GetRenderingParameters(Templates.ContainerRenderingParams.ID, Templates.ContainerRenderingParams.Fields.ShowIcon) == "1",
                    CSSClass = Utility.GetRenderingParameters(Templates.ContainerRenderingParams.ID, Templates.ContainerRenderingParams.Fields.CssClass)
                };
```

**Helper method:**

```
public static string GetRenderingParameters(ID renderingParametersTemplateID, ID renderingParametersTemplateFieldID)
        {
            string parametersTemplateFieldNameInRendering = "Parameters Template";
            string renderingParameters = string.Empty;
            Rendering currentRendering = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering;

            if (currentRendering != null)
            {
                Item currentRenderingItem = GetItem(System.Convert.ToString(currentRendering.RenderingItem.ID));

                Template template = TemplateManager.GetTemplate(renderingParametersTemplateID, Context.Database);
                TemplateField templateField = template.GetFields(true).Where(x => x.ID == renderingParametersTemplateFieldID).FirstOrDefault();
                renderingParameters = templateField != null ? currentRendering.Parameters[templateField.Name] : string.Empty;
            }

            return renderingParameters;
        }
```

Comment: What if you have only 1 checkbox field to Rendering Parameter, does it behave the same?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal There is another rendering paramater with two checkbox fields and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar type of issue where I used checkbox in rendering parameter to create component flag based. I raised the ticket to the Sitecore Support portal and **it's a bug in Sitecore version**.

**Sitecore suggested:** As a workaround, please consider the parameter value as true if it is present and equals to 1.

**Find below the Sitecore Support Response on the same:**

Based on the provided information we would like to define the scope of the current case:

*Issue definition:* False value for bool rendering parameter is retrieved as null.

*Investigation target:* we will work diligently to help find the root cause and a resolution to the defined issue.

*Additional notes:*

- if new circumstances are revealed during the course of the investigation, the scope can be changed based on the mutual agreement;
- overall investigation course will be aligned with Sitecore general Scope Of Support: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/463549;
- questions that are not related to the investigation scope should be registered as separate cases: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/004553.

Thank you for reporting the issue. I was able to reproduce it locally and registered a bug for the current Sitecore version. To track the future status of this bug report, please use `reference number 502996`.

More information about public reference numbers can be found here: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0853187

As a workaround, please consider the parameter value as true if it is present and equals to 1.